# What does np.einsum('mk,nk', D, D) do?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I'm reading over someone else's code and am unsure what np.einsum does in this case.

```
print(np.einsum('mk,nk', D, D)) # D is an np array with shape (3, 100)
```

This code outputs an array with shape (3, 3).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Heres the documentation indicating what it does --> https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Answer (score 1):

There are four steps to convert your equation to einsum notation. Lets take this equation as an example `C[i,k] = sum_j A[i,j] * B[j,k]`

First we drop the variable names. We get `ik = sum_j ij * jk`
We drop the sum_j term as it is implicit. We get `ik = ij * jk`
We replace * with ,. We get `ik = ij, jk`
The output is on the RHS and is separated with -> sign. We get ij, jk -> ik
The einsum interpreter just runs these 4 steps in reverse. All indices missing in the result are summed over.

Here are some more examples from the docsstrong text

```
# Matrix multiplication
einsum('ij,jk->ik', m0, m1)  # output[i,k] = sum_j m0[i,j] * m1[j, k]

# Dot product
einsum('i,i->', u, v)  # output = sum_i u[i]*v[i]

# Outer product
einsum('i,j->ij', u, v)  # output[i,j] = u[i]*v[j]

# Transpose
einsum('ij->ji', m)  # output[j,i] = m[i,j]

# Trace
einsum('ii', m)  # output[j,i] = trace(m) = sum_i m[i, i]

# Batch matrix multiplication
einsum('aij,ajk->aik', s, t)  # out[a,i,k] = sum_j s[a,i,j] * t[a, j, k]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would you say is the equation represented by np.einsum('mk,nk', D, D)? After some more playing around with the code, I figured that np.einsum('mk,nk', D, D) = D @ D.T. However, this doesn't seem to fit with the format of the equation that you suggested: C[i,k] = sum_j A[i,j] * B[j,k]

Comment: `D@D.T` is the simplest description.  Rewriting it as `np.einsum(mk,kn->mn', D, D.T)` makes that more obvious.